# VUEJS 2: Events. Parent to trigger an method found in a child component

Tags: vuejs2

As far as i can tell Events in VUEJS provide a way to inform your parent components of changes in children.
as per : https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-communication/

using :

```
<my-component v-on:myEvent="parentHandler"></my-component>
```

Firing an Event from the child to inform parent by:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    fireEvent() {
      this.$emit('myEvent', eventValueOne, eventValueTwo);
    }
  }
}
```

I would like the parent to trigger an method found in a child component, so i can do something prior to continuing to 'finish' something at the parent level.  Can this be done?

Comment: actually just found link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632711/vue-2-0-parent-to-child-events    will see if this answers my question

Comment: yes, link above solved the problem.  Using Watcher.