# Vue - On Click on Button (Parent), emit data from child-component

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, emit

this may seem simple but I have no clue as how to achieve this pattern of logic in vue:
I have a form, with a child component, the child component renders some input fields which i want to get (via emit or something) when in the parent component the "save" button gets pressed. any ideas?

My idea: On every blur of the input fields in the child component, emit the data to the parent, but that would be quite many emits so i think theres a better solution right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call function on child component on parent events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632711/how-to-call-function-on-child-component-on-parent-events)

Comment: thx ill go check that one out then