# How i can run method from child component vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have parent and chidl component... I need to run child method, when i click on button in parent.
Example code:

Parent

```
<template>
 <child-component></child-component>
 <button>Open Modal in child Component (set modal = true in child component)</button>
</template>
```

Child:

```
<template>
<div v-if="modal">
 <button @click="modal = false">Close</button>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
     modal: false
    }
  } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Here you can find a similar problem with a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45463576/4267716

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this via different implementations. The most common one is via `emit` (another alternative is via dispatching actions if you are using the Redux pattern)

First, you want to catch the even on the parent component and `emit` an event. So this should be your template.

```
<template>
 <child-component></child-component>
 <button @click="click">Open Modal in child Component (set modal = true in child component)</button>
</template>
```

Then you have to `emit` an event (from the parent component) on the function called when a `click` was made.
Something like:

```
click: function() {
  this.$emit('update');
}
```

Lastly, your child component needs to "hear" that event. You can achieve that with something like that on the `created` function of the child component:

```
this.$parent.$on('update', this.updateModal);
```

`this.updateModal` is a function on your child component which just flips the value of the boolean.

Answer (score 0):

In vue you can pass a function as a prop. So you could add a function to alternate model within your parent component then pass it into your child so it can be used normally. I'll put a simple example below.

*small edit, you can bind a class like a hidden/reveal class using the status which is bound to the modal state*

```
// Html
<div id="app">
     <child v-bind:on-click="toggleModal" v-bind:status="modal" />
</div>


// Parent Component
var sample = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data: {
        modal: false
     },
     methods: {
        toggleModal() {
           this.modal = !this.modal
        }
     }
});

// Child component with function prop
Vue.component('child', {
     props: {
        onClick: Function,
        status: Boolean
     }
     template: '<button v-on:click="onClick()">Press Me</div>'
});
```