# How do i reset a child component's search-input

Tags: vue.js, algolia

I have a child component that contains a search input which is `CriminalSearch.vue`, algolia vue-instantsearch for the full question i put it here..

https://gist.github.com/abrhambas01/84518e8437ae2ff1a0dc3dfca202fd00

Comment: You use watchers in the child component to watch for changes to the prop passed by the parent to the child. You pass a prop to the child from parent and change that prop to trigger an event at the child. Would be helpful if instead of the link, only the relevant code was pasted here.

Comment: what do u mean ? Could u please givem e a sample code ?

Comment: Please have a look at this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632711/how-to-call-function-on-child-component-on-parent-events. Seems like there are multiple ways of doing this. Please read the top 3 answers. I hope it helps.