# What prevents the hiding of a load more button at the right time in this Vue 3 app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have been working on a news app, using Vue 3 and the [News API](https://newsapi.org/). I am currently working on a "load more (articles)" functionality.

The initial number of articles is 24 and, if the total number of articles is greater then the current number of articles, there is a button with the text "Load more articles" at the bottom of the page.

In `src\components\ArticleList.vue` I have:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="articles && articles.length" class="row">
    <div
      v-for="article in articles"
      :key="article._id"
      class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3"
    >
      <ArticleCard :article="article" />
    </div>
    
    <div v-show="isMore" class="mb-3 text-center">
      <LoadMoreButton @load-more="loadMore" text="Load more articles" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <p v-if="totalResults == 0" class="text-center">No articles to display</p>
</template>

<script>
import ArticleCard from "./ArticleCard.vue";
import LoadMoreButton from "./LoadMoreButton.vue";

export default {
  name: "NewsList",
  components: { ArticleCard, LoadMoreButton },

  props: {
    whatToShow: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

    searchString: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: "",
    },
  },

  data: () => ({
    language: "en",
    page_size: 24,
    current_page: 1,
    totalResults: 1,
    articles: [],
  }),

  mounted() {
    this.getArticles();
  },

  watch: {
    whatToShow() {
      this.getArticles();
    },

    searchString() {
      this.getArticles();
    },
  },

  computed: {
    isMore() {
      // Check if the total number of pages is grater then the current page
      let totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalResults / this.page_size);
      return totalPages > this.current_page;
    },
  },

  methods: {
    getArticles() {
      const endpoint = `${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL}/${this.whatToShow}?q=${this.searchString}&language=${this.language}&pageSize=${this.page_size}&page=${this.current_page}&apiKey=${process.env.VUE_APP_API_KEY}`;

      this.$axios
        .get(endpoint)
        .then((response) => {
          this.totalResults = response.data.totalResults;
          this.articles = [...this.articles, ...response.data.articles];
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },

    loadMore() {
      if (this.isMore) {
        this.current_page++;
        this.getArticles();
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

In `src\components\LoadMoreButton.vue` I have:

```
<template>
  <button class="btn btn-md btn-success" @click="$emit('load-more')">
    {{ text }}
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "LoadMoreButton",

  props: {
    text: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: "Load more",
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

I use the `isMore` computed property (Boolean) to hide the button's container if there are no more articles to load.

However, after the last click on the `LoadMoreButton`, *before* it disappears, *no additional articles are loaded*.

And the *error code* in the response is "maximumResultsReached".

There is a sandbox **[HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-chandrasekhar-r5jn5j?file=/src/components/ArticleList.vue)** with all the code.

What am I doing wrong?
What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to track that `maximumResultsReached` property from the server, and once it's true set `isMore` to `false`. It seems like a less complicated approach.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: You said that you get from the server ```maximumResultsReached```, so once you receive that change ```isMore``` to ```false```

Comment: `maximumResultsReached` is what I get as an error. That error should not be reached at all.

Comment: What a strange approach to throw an error once the end is reached. What is ```totalResults``` then? It also comes from the server.

Comment: But even if it's an error you just catch it and check. And if ```maximumResultsReached``` then you set ```isMore``` to ```false```.

Answer (score -1):

Your loadMore is wanting a boolean from your computed property and only runs if it is true: you are only checking for greater than which will return false if it is equal to. So the last page and total number of pages should be the same integer value and return true to load last part of your data.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: Use an equal to or greater than operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Greater_than_or_equal